# Serve arbitrary assets on the same port as webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

What is the best way to serve arbitrary assets with `webpack-dev-server`?

I want to be able to server all my assets, those bundled by the `webpack-dev-server` and other assets like images that are in a directory from the same address --  what's the best pattern for doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CopyWebpackPlugin, which will copy files to your build output directory, and works with webpack-dev-server:

```
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
//...  later in plugins[]
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { // copy all contents of 'public' folder over to output directory
        from: 'src/public'
    }
],
```

If you didn't want to do that for some reason, you could proxy requests to a certain path to another directory using the top-level (along with 'entry', 'plugins, etc. in webpack.config.js) devServer config:

```
devServer: {
    port: 5001,
    quiet: false,
    stats: { color: true },
    proxy: {
        "/api/*": {
            target: 'http://localhost:5000',
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true,
            ignorePath: false,
        },
    }
},
```

This is for my use case, any requests to webpack-dev-server running on port 5001 that go to a url starting with /api/ get proxied to a web server running on port 5000 with the same path.  I.e. if you call '/api/values' from the page running in the webpack-dev-server, it will proxy the request to 'http://localhost:5000/api/values'

Comment: Thanks very much for outlining some options!